# Getting access denied for user in WAMP

Tags: php, mysqli, wampserver

I tried connecting to my database in WAMP, it first gave me `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'C:/wamp/www'@'localhost' (using password: NO).`I later changed the password but still getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'C:/wamp/www'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

In phpmyadmin, I added my password to it but nothing change. here is the code for config.inc:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'h]C+{nqW$omNoTIkCwC$%z-LTcy%p6_j$|$Wv[mwngi~|e'; //What you want

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Local Databases';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';//127.0.0.1
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'father2242';

// Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';

// Allow connection without password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

// Suppress Warning about pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;

// To have PRIMARY & INDEX in table structure export
//$cfg['Export']['sql_drop_table'] = true;
//$cfg['Export']['sql_if_not_exists'] = true;

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/';
/* End of servers configuration */

?>
```

For my database connection parameters (db.ini):

```
;MySQLi hostname
host = localhost

;MySQLi Username
user = root

;MySQLi Password
pass = father2242

;MySQLi Table - Database
name = ddrive
```

Script for accessing the connection(database.php)

```
<?php

    function DB() {

        $dbconfig = (object) parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/../ini/db.ini');

        try {

            $db = new PDO(
                "mysql:host={$dbconfig->host};dbname={$dbconfig->name}",
                $dbconfig->user,
                $dbconfig->pass
            );

            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            return $db;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            die($e->getMessage());

        }

    }
?>
```

Why am I getting this error? I am open to suggestions or criticisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 'C:/wamp/www'@'localhost' tells that user you try to connect with is 'C:/wamp/www', not 'root'. Could you check what is actually inside $dbconfig by printing it out?

Changing password in phpmyadmin config doesn't actually change password from database itself. Phpmyadmin is just a client, not database.

To change password from database you should change it in 'users' table in 'mysql' database using any client (like phpmyadmin):

1. Remove username and password from phpmyadmin config - it will allow you to login using web-form.
2. Open phpmyadmin and use default user/password pair. Most likely it is 'root' without password by default.
3. Go to users table, search for 'root' user with 'localhost' host and change password to PASSWORD('father2242')
4. Save row
5. Restart MySQL service

Everything should work after that - you will have root user allowed to access from localhost with password you chose.

Comment: if i use root@localhost as the username, it displays: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root@localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES) but if I use root I get SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'C:/wamp/www'@'localhost' (using password: YES). I did all you suggested.

Comment: What will that say?
`$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ddrive", 'root', '');`

Comment: Then mistake is in `$dbconfig = (object) parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/../ini/db.ini');` - it doesn't get data from db.ini properly - print_r it to check contents.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have amended the  `config.inc.php` file, there is no need.

If you change these 2 lines back to there original state

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'father2242';
```

which was

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

When you run phpMyAdmin you should be presented with the `phpMyAdmin` login page.

NOTE: The `root` userid does not have a password set by default, like most MySQL installs.

So use `Username = root` and leave the `password blank` and this will log you in as the `root` account.

If you did actually set a password on the root account, then you can use that password in the login page.